# "'resource' is not recognized as an internal or external command" while POSTing using Web Service API in SonarQube 5.1.2

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-web

I am using SonarQube 5.1.2 on Windows 7 Professional. I am using Web Service API over cURL 7.32.0 (x86_64-pc-win32). I want to upload sonar.exclusions and few more such properties for a specific project using POST.

I use `curl -u admin:admin -X POST http://localhost:9512/api/prop
erties/?id=sonar.exclusions -v -T "D:\sonar-exclusions.xml"` and I am able to POST it as global sonar.exclusions.

Where as if I use `resource` to post it to a specific project with the command - `curl -u admin:admin -X POST http://localhost:9512/api/prop
erties/?id=sonar.exclusions&resource=org.myProject:myProject -v -T "D:\sonar-exclusions.xml"` I get the error *{"err_code":200,"err_msg":"property created"}'resource' is not recognized as an
internal or external command, operable program or batch file*

What's going wrong with the `resource` parameter here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the `&` in the URL, it's interperted by your command line prompt as: *Let me run this command:*

```
curl -u admin:admin -X POST http://localhost:9512/api/properties/?id=sonar.exclusions
```

*and then run this command:*

```
resource=org.myProject:myProject -v -T "D:\sonar-exclusions.xml"
```

The first one returns `{"err_code":200,"err_msg":"property created"}` while the second one is bound to fail with:

```
'resource' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file
```

You should either escape the `&` or simply put the URL between "quotes".

Comment: Thanks Nicolas for that nice explanation, it worked for me.